# Xcode like "Scheme > Target" selector UI in SwiftUI

Tags: macos, swiftui

I am an experienced iOS developer but a noob in macOS world. Don't have AppKit experience at all. I am working on a macOS app using SwiftUI and wanting to create Xcode like `Scheme > Target` selector UX with ability to pick from menu when clicked on each components in the toolbar (see image below). Are there are handy Views I can use to achieve this or this has to be a custom implementation?

Thanks in advance.

[image: Xcode Scheme and Target Selection UI]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the control as a whole is not available in SwiftUI, the button style it uses is available - `.accessoryBar`. Also, the right chevron is the system image "chevron.compact.right".

You can make something very similar to it like this:

```
@State var picker1 = "Foo"
@State var picker2 = "Bar"

// ...

HStack(spacing: 0) {
    Menu(picker1) {
        Picker("Pick", selection: $picker1) {
            Text("Foo").tag("Foo")
            Text("Foo1").tag("Foo1")
            Text("Foo2").tag("Foo2")
        }
    }
    Image(systemName: "chevron.compact.right")
    Menu(picker2) {
        Picker("Pick", selection: $picker2) {
            Text("Bar").tag("Bar")
            Text("Bar1").tag("Bar1")
            Text("Bar2").tag("Bar2")
        }
    }
}
.pickerStyle(.inline)
// you don't even need this if you are putting it directly in an accessory bar
.buttonStyle(.accessoryBar)
```

The main differences between this and the one in Xcode is:

- the downward chevrons next to the button title is always visible, instead of only visible on hover
- the picker that shows up is a simple menu - there is no "speech bubble triangle" at the top of the menu.

If you need something even more similar, I think you'd need to go down the `NSViewRepresentable` route.

Comment: That's a great start. Thank you. I did not know about `accessoryBar`. Also, thank you for detailed differences. I think I will go with this for now with a `.background` of a `RoundedRectangle` with a darker `.fill()` to that `HStack` to give it a similar look and feel. Appreciate it.